# Non-negative Matrix Factorization for clustering

Tags: matrix-factorisation

I'm learning to user NMF to do clustering.
Based on the reading [What is a good explanation of Non Negative Matrix Factorization?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10299/what-is-a-good-explanation-of-non-negative-matrix-factorization) and https://iksinc.online/2016/03/21/what-is-nmf-and-what-can-you-do-with-it/.
The first link mention for data preprocessing, normalization is necessary.
My question is if we do a normalization for the features there will be negative values in the data. Isn't non-negative necessary for this method?

For NMF,https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html , it seems you still need to define n_component before hand. Does it depend on domain knowledge or any process to help to select? There is one constraint that n_component will be  far less than matrix A(m by n) m or n.